# OnClick Sound breaks off after a few of clicks

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, onclicklistener

When i click on my display, the onClick sound comes per click 1 time. So when i click about 50 times the sound does not come anymore..

```
if (smaragt.getTag(R.id.artsmaragt) == BLAU) {
        final MediaPlayer coin2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.coin1);
        coin2.start();
        punkte += 5;
    }
```

can someone help me ? I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new MediaPlayer each time.  That's expensive and likely your problem.  Create a media player once, and just play it every time the button is clicked.

Comment: And if I want to play different sounds?

Comment: Then make a new one, but make sure to call release() on the old one first.  Or if you have a small number of files, its acceptable to keep a few around.  Just don't keep a lot of them, or you'll hit issues.

Comment: Okay it works thank you! But now the sounds weird is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be creating too many instances of `MediaPlayer` and not release them. Just create one instance of `MediaPlayer` outside of this condition and use only `coin2.start()` to play sound.